# How to find a CM point with the image in the elliptic curve under modular parametrization given

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

everyone! Let $E:y^2+y=x^3-61$ be the minimal model of the elliptic curve 243b. How can I find the CM point $\tau$ in $X_0(243)$ such that $\tau$ maps to the point $(3\sqrt[3]{3},4)$ under the modular parametrization? Can anyone tell me the answer or how to use sagemath to find it?

I use the sagemath code

```
EllipticCurve([0,0,1,0,-61])
phi = EllipticCurve([0,0,1,0,-61]).modular_parametrization()
f=phi.power_series(prec = 10000)[1]
f.truncate(20000)
```

to get the parametrization of y coordinate, then I use

```
q=var('q')
f(q)=
df=diff(f,q)              
NewtonIt(q)=q-(f/df)(q)
xn=e^(2*pi*I*a/20.031)                      
for i in range(1000):
    xn=N(NewtonIt(xn),digits=2000)
print xn
```

to get the numerical $e^{2\pi i \tau}$. After taking log and dividing by $2 \pi i$, I get the numerical $\tau$. But if I use

```
z=
p=z.algebraic_dependency(100)
```

I get the wrong polynomial. Why?

Comment: any method is welcome！

Comment: In principle you can compute a fundamental domain of $X_0(N)$ which reduces to the problem to that of finding a root of an analytic function on some compact domain. The standard way to compute the image $\varphi(\tau)$ under the modular parametrisation is to integrate the differential form $\omega_f =2\pi if(\tau) d\tau$ from $\infty$ to $\tau$, which gives you a complex number and thus a point of $E$ via the Weierstrass functions. You may also be interested by the PhD theses of Christophe Delaunay and Hao Chen, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2827v2

Comment: @Brunault Thanks a lot, Francois! I find the numerical approximation using the Newton method, but I can not find the exact CM point.  It should be an algebraic number,  but I can not recover it from the numerical approximation.

Comment: If you have a numerical approximation you can try using PARI/GP `algdep()`, Mathematica `RootApproximant[]`, or equivalent function of some CAS for find the irreducible polynomial for the number. Maybe your approximation is wrong?

Comment: Not all preimages are CM points, so one needs a priori to locate all the preimages (possible in theory using the residue theorem applied to finer and finer subdivisions of the fundamental domain). As you see, this problem is not easy.

Comment: @François Brunault  I think it should be CM points, since the image of non-CM points will be transcendental.

Comment: Maybe there is something I don't understand in your particular situation, but in general, most algebraic points on the modular curve are not CM, yet map to algebraic points on E. And there are many preimages (you can calculate the degree of $\phi $ in Sage).

Comment: If your point $(3\sqrt[3]{3},4)$ is in the torsion $E[m]$, find $p$ such that $m | a_p = p+1 - \# E(F_p)$, then $O = a_p \phi(\{i\infty, \tau\}) = \phi(T_p\{i\infty, \tau\})$ which leads to the equation $T_p\{i\infty, \tau\} = \phi^{-1}(O)$ in $H_1(X_0(N),\Bbb{Q})$

Comment: @reuns This point is not torsion.

Comment: Yes, this point is not torsion

Comment: @François Brunault,  Dear Francois, can you give me some references for your last comment?

Comment: The j-invariant of a CM point is an algebraic integer, while a random algebraic number will not be an algebraic integer. As a check you compute the j-invariant of your tau, it should be an algebraic number of degree at most $3 \times \deg \phi$ since your original point has degree 3.

Comment: @François Brunault Thanks a lot!